# Gitlab uses wrong url when browsing repositories

Tags: gitlab

I've installed Gitlab EE behind nginx proxy. The external address is `https://git.myserver.com`
After that, I had to change the external URL according to this page: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html

I've changed external_url in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb to `https://git.myserver.com`, then `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `gitlab-ctl restart`

Now when I log in, I get to the dashboard. I can create a project, but there is a first clue that something is wrong. It says I can clone the repo by using command

`git clone https://myserver.com/gitlab/myuser/myproject.git`

That's not right and sure enough, I can use the repository by using origin

`https://git.myserver.com/myuser/myproject.git`

Repo works fine. I can clone and push, but the GUI is somehow messed up.

I can open my project page in the gui on this address:

`https://git.myserver.cz/myuser/myproject`

I see all the files, but when I wan to click on one, I get redirected to

`https://git.myserver.cz/gitlab/myuser/myproject`

And of course it gives me 404, I have to delete the `gitlab/` part in the URL

I haven't find any other suspicious configuration in the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.

I've done no customization to the gitlab EE except for changing the external_url.

**I use Gitlab version 12.4.2-ee**

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared when I updated gitlab to 12.7.5-ee